# Help with attr, mouseenter, and mouseout not functioning correctly

Tags: jquery, attr, mouseout, mouseenter

I can't get the attr function to change the class and keep it until the next click. It also won't use the new mouseenter and mouseout functions. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

### HTML

```
<a href="" id="play" class="pause"><div id="playctrl"><img id="pausectrl" class="play" src="images/play1.png" ></div></a>
```

### JQUERY

```
$('.pause').click(function(){
    $('#pausectrl').attr({
        src: 'images/pause1.png',
        class: 'paused' 
    });

    return false;
});

$('.play').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/play2.png');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/play1.png');
});

$('.paused').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/pause2.png');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/pause1.png');
});
```

Here is a link to a sample of the page. [MMA Slideshow controls sample](http://insightdezign.net/mma/p_sacredharbor.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

> It also won't use the new mouseenter
>   and mouseout functions

I am guessing that it is because when your code runs, your objects don't have the class yet so they aren't bound to the eventhandlers. You could use the live function to bind your event correctly.

```
$('.pause').click(function(){
    $('#pausectrl').attr({
        src: 'images/pause1.png',
        class: 'paused' 
    });
  return false;
});

$('.play').live("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).attr('src','images/play2.png');
});

$('.play').live("mouseout", function(){
  $(this).attr('src','images/play1.png');
});

$('.paused').live("mousenter", function() {
  $(this).attr('src','images/pause2.png');
});


$('.paused').live("mouseout", function(){
  $(this).attr('src','images/pause1.png');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem with the state not holding after a click. I still have a problem with it not changing back after second click.

Comment: For that, you could use the toggle function instead of the click event handler: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you! Works like a charm now. I'm new to Stackoverflow. Should I post my finished code up here somewhere in case someone else has a question like mine?

Answer (score 4):

You're setting `src` on the link. You want to do this instead:

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'myimage.png');
```

Comment: First, Thank you for your help. The mouseover and mouseout lesson made perfect sense. I corrected that. I'm not sure I understand on the the second problem though. Are you referring to the link in the HTML? If so how would I use this? Sorry I'm pretty new at Jquery but learning quickly. Thanks again.

Comment: Correct, you're essentially setting `<a href="" id="play" class="pause" src="images/play2.png">`. You want to set the `src` on the `<img>` *inside* the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the src on the wrong tag, use the following code instead:

`$("img.play", $(this)).attr('src', 'thenewimage.png');`

The part '$(this)' is the start position where jQuery is trying to find a image with the class 'play'. This is in my opinion a efficient solution..

the complete js code:

```
$('.play').mouseenter(function(){
  $("img.play", $(this)).attr('src','images/play2.png');
  }).mouseout(function(){
  $("img.play", $(this)).attr('src','images/play1.png');
  });
```

The HTML stays the same..

```
$('.paused').mouseenter(function(){
  $("img.play", $(this)).attr('src','images/pause2.png');
  }).mouseout(function(){
  $("img.play", $(this)).attr('src','images/pause1.png');
  });
```

`

Comment: This makes complete sense to me and yet it is still not functioning. The old way used the images on mouseenter and mouseout initially but not the new ones. This does not use the images for mouseenter or mouseout. The pause1.png image loads when clicked but does not change back when clicked again. I just know I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: You say 'clicked'? Your code says on mouseEnter instead of onClick.. If you'd like to change your images when clicking on the image see the jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/click/ for all mouse events and examples see: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: No, I'm using both together. When the page loads it loads with the image play1.png. Then on mouseEnter it changes to play2.png. If you click on it It should change to pause1.png and then if you mouseEnter it should change to pause2.png. Clicking again would bring it back to the play images. This is the reason for 2 sets of mouseEnter and mouseout controls each bound to a different class. The onclick function will call for the class change.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part:

```
$('.paused').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','images/pause2.png');
  }).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','images/pause1.png');
});
```

You would be better off setting a class name with jQuery and using CSS and [image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for the image replacement.

Something like:

```
.paused {background: url(/images/paused.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}
.paused:hover {background-position: 0 15px;} /* Or whatever the position in the sprite */
```

Comment: I chose to put the link on a div because I wanted to control the size of the link to smaller than the image and have the image overflow the div. (the text when you hover is outside of the constraints of the box) If I used a sprite and allowed overflow wouldn't the whole thing show up?